# Webpack. Ошибка после обновления

Tags: javascript, webpack

Всем привет. После обновления webpack с версии 2.7.0 до 4.39.3 возникла ошибка.

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (TypeError: Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined
at DllReferencePlugin.apply (***\node_modules\webpack\lib\DllReferencePlugin.js:32:18)
at Compiler.apply (C:\Users\User\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:306:16)
at webpack (C:\Users\User\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:32:19)
at attachWebpackDevMiddleware (C:\Users\User\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\WebpackDevMiddleware.js:68:20)
at C:\Users\User\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\WebpackDevMiddleware.js:247:21
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\WebpackDevMiddleware.js:210:32)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:276:13)
at Server.emit (events.js:188:13)
at emitListeningNT (net.js:1289:10)
)
```

Пробовал переустановить пакеты npm, но это не дало результатов.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: посмотри возможно изменились настройки DllReferencePlugin https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/#dllplugin в webpack.config.js

Comment: Вроде все так же.

Comment: DllReferencePlugin в webpack.config.js `new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
        context: __dirname,
        manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
      })`

Comment: Попробуйте переустановить более старую стабильную версию